# What is the relative path root of DeploymentItemAttribute?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, deploymentitem

Using [MSTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx), what is the relative path root of the [DeploymentItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) page...

> Relative paths are relative to the
>   RelativePathRoot setting found in the
>   .testrunconfig file.

That setting is, by default, the **Solution directory**. So, if you have this project structure

```
SecretProject\
    ComponentA\
    ComponentA.Test\
        Resources\
            required.xml
        ComponentA.Test.csproj
        Tests.cs
    SecretProject.sln
```

And you want to deploy **required.xml**, you're going to create a DeploymentItemAttribute like this

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem("ComponentA.Test\Resources\required.xml")]
    public void Test() 
    {

    }
}
```

It seems the file properties need to be set to '**Content**' and '**Copy always**' or 'Copy if newer'. There are advanced examples on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: "It seems the file properties need to be set to 'Content' and 'Copy always' or 'Copy if newer'." You'd be surprised how hard it was to find this...

Comment: @SouthShoreAK - Where was it found?

Comment: @ScottLangham It's in the File properties of the deployment Item. In the 'Solution Explorer' you need to highlight the file (in this case 'required.xml'), right click it and select properties. You should see it there.

Comment: How could this be the correct answer? The RelativePathRoot is the Output path (bin\Debug\) defined in Project properties -> Build. It's not the project directory by default.

Answer (score 1):

To assume that the RelativePathRoot default is the dir where your solution resides was not correct in my case, nor was RelativePathRoot defined within my .testrunconfig file. I found the RelativePathRoot default to be the /bin/debug dir for the solution.

Walking back from that point, then walking up to my file that I was attempting to deploy for the unit test worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm gonna add my experience.

So if you're using .testrunconfig file, that will trump (override) what I'm saying below.

I figured there were a few options.

> Relative to the current .csproj
>
> Relative to the .sln
>
> Relative to the current .cs file

I finally got my build system working by using the "**relative to the current .cs file**" approach.

In my example, I needed a Xsd from a different project copied over for my UnitTest.  But the type of file does not matter.

Example:

> c:\myfolder\MyXsdProject\XSDs\MyCoolXsd.xsd
>
> c:\myfolder\MyCsharpUnitTestProject\MySubFolder1\MySubFolder2\MyUnitTestClass.cs

```
namespace MyCsharpUnitTestProject.MySubFolder1.MySubFolder2
{

    [TestClass]
    [DeploymentItem(@"..\..\..\MyXsdProject\XSDs\MyCoolXsd.xsd")]

    public class MyUnitTestClass
    {
    }
}
```