# MSTest Deployment Item not copied

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I am new to unit testing and I am trying to test my code with deployed file. Unfortunately this file does not get copied, when starting the test.

The file to copy is located here:

```
SolutionDirectory/UnitTestProject/data/testCourseData.xml
```

This is my test code (i shortened it):

```cs
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("UnitTestProject\\data\\testCourseData.xml", "data")]
public void TestCourseConstructor()
{
...
courseActual.ReadXMLConfig(@"data\testCourseData.xml");
...
}
```

I did some research and I went through several solution approachs:

1. I have set the xml file build settings to **Resource** and also to **Embedded resource** and to **Always copy**
2. In older posts they say I have to navigate to *Test->Test settings->Deployment* and activate deployment, but this menu seems to be no longer existing in newer versions of Visual Studio (I am using VS Pro 2022 64Bit, V17.8.7)
3. I have added a .runsettings file to UnitTestProject (location now *UnitTestProject/.runsettings*) with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- configuration elements -->
    <MSTest>
        <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
        <DeploymentEnabled>True</DeploymentEnabled>
    </MSTest>
</RunSettings>
```

4. I chose the option *Test->Configure Runtimesettings->Choose Runsettings file* and selected the file above.

None of those things are working.

In addition the posts in Stackoverflow are all extremely old. Should I use **nUnit** instead?

Thanks in advance for your advices!

**EDIT**:
I forgot to add the error message on test end.

```
 Test method UnitTestProject.UnitTest_Course.TestCourseConstructor threw exception: 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'G:\NewFolderStructure\Creative\Programming\C#\WPF\LearningManagementSystem\TestResults\Deploy_jensz 20240322T175537\Out\data\testCourseData.xml'.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822612/what-is-the-relative-path-root-of-deploymentitemattribute

Comment: Ok thanks, that led me to the right direction. For anyone facing the same problem a quick recap what I discovered based on this article: Independent on the folder specified, the deployed file will **always** be copied to the _testproject/bin/debug folder_, while the relative paths within the test arrangement will lead to _testresults/subfolder_.
That was point A, point B is - as described in the answers above - the file-to-deploy has to be marked as **content** and not as **resource/embedded resource**

Thanks again for the hint into the correct direction.